# Кодировка csv файла в exсel python

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

У меня есть код   (не весь)

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
            print(arr[i])
            page = requests.get(arr[i])
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
            first_class = soup.find_all('dd' )

            for a in first_class:
                a = a.get_text()

                a = a.strip('\n')
                new_arr.append(a)

            with open('flat.csv' , 'a',encoding='utf-8')as f :
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                for i in range (len(arr)):
                    writer.writerow([arr[i] , new_arr,])
```

Рузультат в сsv [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если я изменю разширение csv to txt все хорошо (нормальный русский)
Что делать? Япробовал .encode на string не работает

Comment: код у вас сохраняет файл, используя utf-8. Если вы в Excel хотите посмотреть, то убедитесь, что он utf-8, а не к пример cp1251 кодировку использует, чтобы csv текст декодировать из байт.

Comment: как проверить exel2016?

Comment: это можно как отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос спросить: «как открыть csv файл, используя utf-8 кодировку в Excel» (не только вам может пригодиться)